# show the activities of the child record on the activity feed of the aprent

Tags: lightning, activities, parent

In Lightning, is it possible to show the activities of the child Account record on the Parent or the Grandparent?

Scenario:
1. Account record called "ICME".
2. ICME parent is "ICME Group"
3. ICME Group parent account is "ICME Global"

There is a call logged for ICME and shows in the Activity feed for ICME.

Is it possible to get the call logged to show in the activity feed for ICME Group and also ICME Global?

Comment: I do not believe Activities can be related to more than 1 object. This would be a nice feature, but how do you control the number of activities? Account tiers could be 10+, can you imagine the number of Activities for this single case.

Comment: You might be able to display summary data using a report chart.  Maybe you could build a custom lightning component to display all activities from children but it's prob a heavy calculation.